# How can I use "count" and "group by" in Prisma 2?

Tags: react-apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql, redwoodjs

I have this function which works:

```js
export const tagsByLabel = async (params) => {
  const findManyParams = {
    where: { userId: userIdFromSession },
    orderBy: { title: "asc" },
  };
  if (params) {
    const { searchTerm } = params;
    findManyParams.where.title = { contains: searchTerm };
  }
  console.log("findManyParams", findManyParams);
  const tagsByLabelResult = await db.tag.findMany(findManyParams);
  console.log("tagsByLabelResult", tagsByLabelResult);
  return tagsByLabelResult;
};
```

If I search for 'mex', I see:

```json
    findManyParams {
      where: { userId: 1, title: { contains: 'mex' } },
      orderBy: { title: 'asc' }
    }
    tagsByLabelResult [
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'mex',
        description: 'Mexican food',
        userId: 1,
        createdAt: 2020-05-03T22:16:09.134Z,
        modifiedAt: 2020-05-03T22:16:09.134Z
      }
    ]
```

And for an empty query, `tagsByLabelResult` contains all tag records.

**How can I adjust my `tagsByLabel` function to aggregate (using "group by") the records and output a "count" for each record of `tagsByLabelResult` in order by count descending?**

```json
    tagsByLabelResult [
      {
        id: 9,
        title: 'mex',
        description: 'Mexican food',
        count: 25,
        userId: 1,
        createdAt: 2020-05-03T22:16:09.134Z,
        modifiedAt: 2020-05-03T22:16:09.134Z
      }
    ]
```

I see the [docs example](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/crud#count) of `prisma.user.count()`, but that seems to retrieve a simple count of the result of the whole query rather than a count as a field with a "group by".

I'm using RedwoodJs, Prisma 2, Apollo, GraphQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now `groupBy` support is still in spec [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-js/issues/5) so currently you would only be able to use `count` with specific querying.

As a workaround, you would have to use `prisma.raw` for the timebeing.

Comment: Ok, I will look at https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/raw-database-access. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my `tags.sdl.js` I needed to add:

```js
type TagCount {
  id: Int!
  title: String!
  count: Int!
  principles: [Principle]
  description: String
  createdAt: DateTime!
  modifiedAt: DateTime!
}
```

And change query `tagsByLabel(searchTerm: String): [Tag!]!` to `tagsByLabel(searchTerm: String): [TagCount!]!`

In my `TagsAutocomplete.js` component, I now have:

```js
export const TagsAutocomplete = ({ onChange, selectedOptions, closeMenuOnSelect }) => {
  const state = {
    isLoading: false,
  };

  const client = useApolloClient();

  const promiseOptions = useCallback(
    async (searchTerm) => {
      try {
        const { data } = await client.query({
          query: QUERY_TAGS_BY_LABEL,
          variables: { searchTerm },
        });

        console.log("promiseOptions data", data);
        const tags = data.tags.map((tag) => {
          if (!tag.label.includes("(")) {
            //ONEDAY why does the count keep getting appended if this condition isn't checked here?
            tag.label = tag.label + " (" + tag.count + ")";
          }
          return tag;
        });
        console.log("promiseOptions tags", tags);
        return tags;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error fetching tags", e);
      }
    },
    [client]
  );
};
```

And in my `tags.js` service, I now have:

```js
export const tagsByLabel = async (params) => {
  let query = `
      SELECT t.*, COUNT(pt.B) as count FROM tag t LEFT JOIN _PrincipleToTag pt ON t.id = pt.B WHERE t.userId = ${userIdFromSession} `;

  if (params) {
    const { searchTerm } = params;
    if (searchTerm) {
      query += `AND t.title LIKE '%${searchTerm}%' `;
    }
  }
  query += "GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY count DESC, t.title ASC;";
  console.log("query", query);
  const tagsByLabelResult = await db.raw(query);
  //TODO get secure parameterization working
  console.log("tagsByLabelResult", tagsByLabelResult);
  return tagsByLabelResult;
};
```

But, as mentioned in the comment, I'm still trying to figure out how to get [secure parameterization](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1929#issuecomment-623712981)  working.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, you may have figured out how to securely parameterize but here's how I did it in case you haven't yet. 

Based on: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/raw-database-access#executeraw 

I managed to get it working here: https://gist.github.com/Aidurber/a8c9b97b994fa4a0e46a9243ba378a79

It's really ugly and I can't find a clean abstraction to make this a little more generic but it does the trick.

Comment: @ZeroBased_IX Thanks for your note; I'll check that out.